# Can't send commands in ARD/Automator

Tags: automator, remote-desktop

I work at a school that manages various computer labs, some of which are iMacs.  To manage our iMac labs we use Automator/Apple Remote Desktop on a Mac Server.

Recently we updated ARD to the latest version and now we're experiencing an odd problem.  Whenever a computer is restarted through Automator and has booted back up to the login screen, ARD can no longer detect it (And therefore none of our automator commands will work).  It's odd because in ARD it lists the status of the computers as "ARD Not Active", but we can still click the control/observe buttons and remote into the computers.  We just can't send command/tasks.

I was able to reproduce the problem without requiring a full reboot by creating a task in Automator or ARD that runs "killall loginwindow".

Other info that might be useful:

- When I restart a computer from within ARD, when it boots back up ARD will detect it.
- When I create a workflow in Automator just 2 tasks, "Choose Computer List" and "Restart Computer", the problem occurs.
- Our server is currently running Mountain Lion.

Our fix right now is closing ARD and reopening it.  It's a problem because a bunch of our workflows require restarts and can't complete without our manual intervention.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my personal opinion, using ARD and Automator for managing Macs is not a streamlined solution. Why don’t you look into Profile Manager for Mountain Lion Server?

Comment: What version of ARD and OS are the clients using?